# Problemas con JOIN MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Salduos amigos, la verdad tengo un serio problema, tengo varias tablas que almacenan cierta informacion de los usuarios como su facebook, twitter, instagram, imagen, email, etc...

Mostraré el SQL y explico el problema:

---

```
SELECT  
        IFNULL(empresa_twitter.twitter,users.twitter) AS    user_twitter,
        users.id        AS  user_id,
        users.status        AS  user_status,
        users.grants        AS  user_grants,
        Lower(users.admin)  AS  user_admin,
        users.webmail       AS  user_webmail,
        users.PLAN      AS  user_plan,
        users.username      AS  user_username,
        users.facebook      AS  user_facebook,
        users.instagram     AS  user_instagram,
        users.twitter       AS  user_twitter,
        Trim(Lower(users.nombre))AS user_nombre,
        Trim(users.about)   AS  user_about,
        Lower(users.email)  AS  user_email,
        IFNULL(Lower(empresa_imagen.imagen),users.imagen)   AS  user_imagen,
        IFNULL(Lower(empresa_facebook.facebook),users.facebook) AS  user_facebook,
        IFNULL(Lower(empresa_instagram.instagram),users.instagram)  AS  user_instagram,
        Lower(paises.pais)  AS  pais_nombre,
        Lower(paises.iso2)  AS  pais_code,
        Lower(paises.moneda)    AS  pais_moneda,
        Lower(paises.simbolo_moneda)    AS  pais_simbolo,
        Lower(paises.bandera)   AS  pais_bandera,
        IFNULL(SUM(ingresos.monto), 0)  AS  ingresos,
        IFNULL(SUM(egresos.monto),  0)  AS  egresos
FROM users, paises
LEFT    JOIN ingresos ON    ingresos.user   =   1907
LEFT    JOIN egresos ON egresos.user    =   1907
LEFT    JOIN empresa_imagen ON  empresa_imagen.user =   1907
LEFT    JOIN empresa_facebook ON    empresa_facebook.user = 1907
LEFT    JOIN empresa_instagram ON   empresa_instagram.user = 1907
LEFT    JOIN empresa_twitter ON empresa_twitter.user = 1907
WHERE users.id  =   1907
  AND   paises.iso2 =   users.pais
```

---

El problema existe cuando en el primer SELECT busco el twitter en la tabla empresa_twitter, ya que me muestra el twitter almacenado en la tabla users en caso de que empresa_twitter esté NULL o vacío, pero:

No me muestra el registro mas reciente (el último registro),
Intento hacer un MAX(IFNULL()) pero me causa error, solo quiero obtener el ultimo registro de su twitter, facebook, instagram, imagen, etc...
Pero a la vez sumarlo a los resultados...

1, usuario, email, facebook.com, twitter.com, instagram.com, etc...

---

Tabla empresa_facebook

```
_____________________________________________________________
| ID  |      user      | user_facebook |        fecha        |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  56 |    1907        | axer.xiche    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  57 |    1907        | arc.guevara    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Tabla users

```
_________________________________________________________________
|   ID  |      username  | user_facebook   |       fecha         |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1907 |    arcaelas    | usuario_default | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Ahora lo que necesito es que el me seleccione los campos de la tabla users donde el id = 1907 y el ultimo registro de la tabla empresa_twitter,
pero en caso de que no exista el registro en la tabla empresa_twitter me muestre  el resultado de la tabla users, lo hice con un

```
    IFNULL(empresa_twitter.twitter, users.twitter)
```

Y hasta ahi vamos bien, pero todo se daña cuando quiero que me muestre el último registro ya que lo intenté con

```
    MAX(IFNULL(empresa_twitter.twitter, users.twitter))
    LAST(IFNULL(empresa_twitter.twitter, users.twitter))
```

¿Y devuelven error, que debo hacer o como debo ejecutar la consulta?

Lo que intento es no realizar consultas separadas para evitar mas peso en el servidor, ya que MySql sabemos como trabaja a diferencia de Postgrel, 
Quien tenga una buena solución se lo agradecería en el alma y la empresa tambien.

Comment: formatea tu código así es dificil de leer, al momento de seleccionarlo busca el ícono de {} con eso quedará mejor

Comment: No se formateó todo, pero a partir del FROM ya está organizado...

Comment: Puedes añadir unos datos de ejemplo, incluso un ejemplo de como quieres los datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no logro comprender 100% lo que quieres hacer.

Primeramente debes cambiar tu código en los left join de este modo:

```
LEFT    JOIN ingresos ON ingresos.user   =   users.id
LEFT    JOIN egresos ON egresos.user    =   users.id
LEFT    JOIN empresa_imagen ON  empresa_imagen.user =   users.id
LEFT    JOIN empresa_facebook ON empresa_facebook.user = users.id
LEFT    JOIN empresa_instagram ON empresa_instagram.user = users.id
```

Recomiendo utilizar order by para ordernar la resultante por cada tabla empresa (empresa_facebook, empresa_twitter) de la siguiente manera:

```
WHERE users.id  =   1907
 AND  paises.iso2 =   users.pais
ORDER BY empresa_twitter.id DESC, 
         empresa_facebook.id DESC, 
         empresa_imagen.id DESC,
         empresa_instagram.id DESC;
```

Con el order by estarías ordenando la resultante de la consulta, y la cantidad de registros variará de acuerdo a tus datos almacenados.

Si deseas devolver un sólo registro por cada usario puedes agregar **`group by`** o incluso **`limit 1`**

Otra alternativa para devlver un solo registro sería subqueries en vez de los left joins de este modo:

```
IFNULL(Lower(select imagen from empresa_imagen where empresa_imagen.user = users.id order by id desc limit 1),users.imagen) AS  user_imagen,
```